# SQL query: for each state with specific number of sailors

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm starting to learn to write SQL queries. However, I'm still struggling with that.
I had to write a query that gives back for each state that has more than 5 sailors the sailor id and the total number of reservations that he has made. The schemas are as following:

`Slr` (`sid`, `sname`, `rating`, `state`) and 
`Reserves` (`sid`, `bid`, `day`).

Here's my trial:

```
Select slr.state, slr.sid, count(*)
From slr left join Reserves on slr.sid=reserves.sid
Group By s.state
Having count(*) >= 5
```

I know it's not correct, but what can I change ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started.

```
select slr.id
, state
, count(*) records

from slr join
(select state thestate, count(*) staterecords
 from slr
 group by state
 having count(*) >= 5 ) temp on state = thestate
 group by slr.id
```

This gives you the sailor id's in states with 5 or more sailors.  There is nothing in your question that helps me with the part about how many reservations he has made.

Comment: Yeah thank you for mentioning that it's my bad. It says that the reserves table is a table that stores information about sailors and reservations they've made by the past.